# Is there ever a case where a semicolon is required inside of parentheses?

Tags: php

I'm trying to determine if a syntactically necessary semicolon would ever appear within parentheses in PHP.

Example:

(legitimate_statement;)

Does this ever happen? Or would syntactically necessary semicolons only appear outside of expressions/function parameters, etc...?

Comment: What is your use-case? Why are you asking this?

Comment: I'm doing some (legitimate) code injections and I'm trying to figure out if a safe place to inject my code is after the first non-commented, non-quoted, non-bracketed, non-parenthesized, semi colon that occurs after an anchoring pattern. it then occurred to me that the initial anchor pattern might be inside parentheses itself, and if i injected code after a semi colon that is already inside some parenthesized expression, it would cause an error. any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2):

It can, yes.

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
    echo $i . '<br>';
```

2 semicolons right there.

Comment: Syntactically necessary ones at that.

Comment: The things inside the `()` ended by a `;` are actually statements themselves.

Comment: thanks for the help. for is a good example. it's the only one i'm able to think of at the moment. any body else aware of any other examples?

Comment: @Nolan if you read my answer (the real answer), then you would know that `for` is the only statement that has "mutliple semi colons in parens"

Answer (score 0):

Among the many types of statements in PHP, there are many that are defined by an ending`;` character. Take a look at PHP's grammar inside of [`zend_lanaguage_parser.y`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_MASTER/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#418) where you can see what exactly defines a statement in PHP land.